# Creating a LINQ expression to get the correct property at the bottom of a KeyedCollection

Tags: c#, .net, linq, keyedcollection

I'm having some issues refactoring and ordering a list.

I have a class called `DomainCollection` which inherits from `KeyedCollection`.

```
public class DomainCollection<T> : KeyedCollection<ID, T>, IDomainCollection<T> where T : class, IDomainObject
```

I created and filled a list called orders.

```
var orders = new DomainCollection<Order>();
```

An order contains an OrderType which contains its own OrderTypes.  So if we were to have a condition where we can perform some actions, it would look like this

```
if(order.Type.Type.Equals(OrderTypes.InvestmentToBankY))
{
  //Currently: logic where it creates a new list and adds the list to the existing order 
  //list and the very end. 
}
```

Onto my problem. I would like to be able to sort my order list so that my orders with InvestmentToBankY will be either at the bottom or top of my DomainCollection.

Comment: `orders.OrderBy(o => o.Type.Type.Equals(OrderTypes.InvestmentToBankY))`?

Comment: There's nothing in a `KeyedCollection` to sort the collection itself. You'd have to provide the functionality to sort in place yourself or else call `OrderBy` on the collection as you enumerate it. You could also call `ToArray` or `ToList` and then use the inbuilt functionality of the result to sort that, which would not affect the original collection.

Comment: @41686d6564standsw.Palestine  I tried that.

Comment: @Kyuzo `OrderBy` _returns_ an enumerable whose elements are ordered. It does _not_ sort the collection in place. Anyway, I posted an answer below with additional options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to iterate over the elements having orders with `InvestmentToBankY` at the top, you can just use something like:

```
// Add .ToList() if you want to materialize the items immediately.
var orderedOrders = 
    orders.OrderBy(o => o.Type.Type.Equals(OrderTypes.InvestmentToBankY));
foreach (var order in orderedOrders)
{
    // This will follow the desired order.
}
```

If you want to end up with a sorted `DomainCollection`, a not-so-efficient way to do so would be to reconstruct the `DomainCollection` using the new order. Something like the following should work:

```
public class DomainCollection<T> : KeyedCollection<ID, T>, IDomainCollection<T> 
    where T : class, IDomainObject
{
    public DomainCollection() { }

    public DomainCollection(IEnumerable<T> items)
    {
        foreach (var item in items)
            this.Add(item);
    }

    protected override ID GetKeyForItem(T item)
    {
        // TODO: implement GetKeyForItem.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

Then, you can use it as follows:

```
var orderedOrders = 
    orders.OrderBy(o => o.Type.Type.Equals(OrderTypes.InvestmentToBankY));

orders = new DomainCollection(orderedOrders);
```

A better solution that avoids creating a new collection is to rely on the fact that `KeyedCollection` inherits `Collection<T>` whose `Items` property is [*internally*](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/collections/objectmodel/collection.cs,28) a `List<T>` and write our own sorting method that uses either a `Comparison<T>` or an `IComparer<T>` and calls the corresponding `List<T>.Sort` overload. Here's an example of the latter:

```
public class DomainCollection<T> : KeyedCollection<ID, T>, IDomainCollection<T> 
    where T : class, IDomainObject
{
    protected override ID GetKeyForItem(T item)
    {
        // TODO: implement GetKeyForItem.
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }

    public void Sort(IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        ((List<T>)this.Items).Sort(comparer);
    }
}

public class OrderComparer : IComparer<Order>
{
    public int Compare(Order x, Order y)
    {
        return x.Type.Type.Equals(OrderTypes.InvestmentToBankY).
            CompareTo(y.Type.Type.Equals(OrderTypes.InvestmentToBankY));
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
orders.Sort(new OrderComparer());
```